# Deploy c# application with MySql database in VS 2015 using VS Publish Method

Tags: c#, mysql, deployment, publish, visual-studio-2015

I have created a C# application with a MySql database in Visual Studio 2015. I want to deploy my project using the publish method in Visual Studio including the database. I do not know how to deploy the MySQL database so I can use my application on the target computer without installing any MySQL server or database manually. I want that when I install my application on the target computer, it will auto detect the database and work.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: database is `MySql` or `SQL Server` ?

Comment: Are you using separate database server ?

Comment: I would suggest you to use `Sqlite` instead of any other `DB`. If it is going to be used only on one machine and doing that is so simple.

Comment: Database is MySql.

Comment: I developed windows application and using localhost as server for database. Is it possible that on client computer without viewing the database structure they install and use application with database? I searched alot but could not find any possible solution for it.

Comment: I already developed project, so if i use Sq lite have to convert from MySQL to Sq lite and change a lot in coding too.

Answer (score 1):

If you use database storage as server means there is no need to install SQL and mySql Database Software. But you need to configure database in webconfig

Comment: in the development machine i used localhost as server and it's windows application so i set server and db settings in app.config file. But when i want to use it in target machine, do i need to setup ODBC, MySQL DB script query to fully set the database? Is there any way, without showing my database structure to clients, when they install software everything should be done automate?